# QTP/UFT: How to find # of concurrent users using a script?

Tags: concurrency, cmd, qtp

We only have 10 licenses of the antiquated QTP / UFT and sometimes we'll kick off a test when all of the licenses are already being used which causes issues. I've been trying to find a way to query QTP in order to find the # of concurrent users at any given time. Commandline, batch, python, powershell, whatever works is fine.

That way, prior to running a test, I can check how many users there are and if it equals 10, then I can send off an email or ping someone to get off.

Do you think this is possible?

Comment: I dont know if this will help, but see this answer - https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mercuryqtp/55CBTuTpBy4/wINFLvZfQN8J

Comment: Interesting read and seems like it has a solution for permissions of license users but doesn't seem to have a way of retrieving the number of concurrent users.

Answer (score 1):

The QTP CD-ROM/Installable directory has this `LicenseServer\utils` folder.
Under this you can find an exe `WlmAdmin.exe`

It can give you the information of all users (user id, ip, machine name etc ) who has currently launched QTP/UFT by connecting to the license server. Not sure if it has an API to get the information programmatically.

You can check in QTP's help.